Need to Refactor Code - Have a instance method doing too many things
I am currently working on a pre-existing automation test framework where we test a service running in kubernetes. It basically provides backup/restore features for k8s applications.
The backup/replicate/restore requests are submitted by users via specs including policies that perform snap/replicate request in periodic manner.
On a broad level we can 4-5 diff ops (for eg snap/replicate and restore an app) with different variations based on diff spec submitted. What I have here currently is a method posted below where the op takes a bunch of kwargs like parameters and a bunch of if conditions to perform the requested op.
We also need to verify these ops at the backend and the verification sort of depends on the sequence and parameter of the ops performed prior to verify.
https://pastebin.com/50t1SH9X
a sample of args here
application_name = kwargs.pop("application_name")
skip_checks = kwargs.pop("skip_checks", list())
self.skip_checks = skip_checks
start_application = kwargs.pop("start_application", True)
start_auxiliary_resources = kwargs.pop("start_auxiliary_resources", False)
start_pending_volumes = kwargs.pop("start_pending_volumes", False)
start_pending_services = kwargs.pop("start_pending_services", False)
remove_application = kwargs.get("remove_application", True)
is_stateless = kwargs.get("is_stateless", False)
snapshot_count = kwargs.get("snapshot_count", 1)
restore_cycles = kwargs.pop("restore_cycles", 0)
retry_interval = kwargs.get("retry_interval", 60)
is_restore_random = kwargs.get("is_restore_random", False)
restore_attempt = kwargs.get("restore_attempt", 1)
is_restore_validated = kwargs.get("is_restore_validated", True)
remove_snapshot = kwargs.get("remove_snapshot", True)
remove_restore_request = kwargs.get("remove_restore_request", True)
kubernetes_services = list()
modify_kubernetes_service = kwargs.pop("modify_kubernetes_service", False)
suspend_service = kwargs.get("suspend_service", False)
resume_service = kwargs.get("resume_service", False)
create_snapshot = kwargs.get("create_snapshot", False)
.
.
.
if cloud_version:
    CloudApiFactory.set_config(name="cloud_version", value=cloud_version)
cloud_version = CloudApiFactory.get_config(name="cloud_version")
remove_resources = kwargs.pop("remove_resources", None)
validate_configurations = kwargs.pop("validate_configurations", dict())
cloud_cluster = kwargs.get("cluster", None)
 
INFO("Setting the default skip restore if not set")
self.cloud_workflow.set_default_skip_restoring_existing_resources(base=self.base_resources)
 
if start_application:
    kubernetes_services = self.cloud_workflow.deploy_kubernetes_application(application_name=application_name,
                                                                             cloud_version=cloud_version, 
                                                                             skip_checks=skip_checks,
                                                                             **kwargs)
if kwargs.get("cross_ns_restore", False):
      INFO("Cross ns restore WF")
      self.cross_ns_restore(**kwargs)
 
if create_multiple_configs:


I am looking for some suggestions and possibly design patterns or any online ref to refactor such classes and functions
In my mind i m thinking of using specs/configs as a data class and using that for processing. However i still need to perform the operations baseed on diff part of the specs and that involves a bunch of if conditions.
Moreover the validation is also kind of complex with a similar if conditions (validation is a seperate class)

Are you asking if there is a way to simplify the assignment of variables from args?

You have a variable self.skip_checks but you don;t seem to be inside any class.

hi yes I cut some code out to make it much smaller hoping to provide some idea of the general problem

@JonSG I am looking at a more general approach one can take to handle function that take numerous args and currently handle to many branches based on the args
